# SQL Server 2012 Reporting, modifing CSS

Tags: css, sql, reporting, customization

I am trying to modify the CSS file to customize my sql reporting Viewer toolbar.  I have followed the instructions listed on MS site. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345247(v=SQL.90).aspx.  I have Added the

```
<HTMLViewerStyleSheet>MyStyleSheet</HTMLViewerStyleSheet>
```

to the rsreportserver.config file and created a copy of the htmlviewer.css file in this location:

```
 C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQLServer\MSRS11.MSSQLSERVER\ReportingServices\ReportServer\Styles.
```

I made the changes to the styles and restarted sql reporting but nothing has changed.  I have also gone and change the css in

```
 C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS11.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services\ReportManager\Styles
```

for the ReportingServices.css and the webparts.css but again no visual changes.  If I look at the html that is render after the report loads it shows no reference to a css file in the iFrame and I can't seem to find any of the changes.  The changes that I have made, have just be obvious changes like changing the font size on the body and changing the background-color on the buttons, but I am not seeing the changes.  Can someone point in the right direction.

Does the css file need to stay in the C:Program files dir or should it be in a website dir?

I have also looked through the log files when I start and stop sql reporting service and I am not seeing any errors and it show that is was started successfully.

Thanks

Comment: The reason number for not seeing changes on style or scripts is the browser's cache, erase your borwser's cache and see if it helps, to do it in IE bring the developer tools (F12), open the Cache menu, and use the option that suit your needs.

Comment: I tried this and did not help. Tried both Firefox and ie

Comment: This shouldn't require service restart. Perhaps you have several ssrs instances installed?